# Manual inverse transform calculation

Tags: decimal, prediction, calculation, manual, inverse-transform

So I want to return my prediction data to the original form which was previously encoded with One-Hot Encoding. The output of my prediction data is like this:

-1,428807238 1,56575093  1,892480682    0   0   0

-0,837317184 1,818356953 0,864372511    0   0   0

-1,261150565 1,891490001 1,820109799    0   0   0

How to do manual inverse transform calculation? Is it by finding the highest value of each row?